# How to handle the duplicate Timestamps in route map?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am using route map, everything is working fine, even the route is accurate.

Only issue before filtering specific path map look somthing like

[image]

I am guessing the issue is Timestamp, I am giving `1` to `n` rank for each path as timestamp.

table views of map

[image]

My question is How to create measure that change No column this

```
No  Container_No    Events  Lat Lon
1   HLXU111 Dub-Rot 53.33306    -6.24889
1   HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.9225 4.47917
1   HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.225  4.7917
2   HLXU111 Dub-Rot 52.84235105 -6.16893985
2   HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.79675051 4.429912263
2   HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.925  4.4917
3   HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.55237595 -5.79583915
3   HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.533278   3.430639
3   HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.922  4.4791
4   HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.061667   -5.715889
4   HLXU111 Rot-Kara    49.727861   -1.940028
4   HLXU222 Rot-Kara    49.72786    -1.94002
5   HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.08522105 -5.4050098
```

To

```
No  Container_No    Events  Lat Lon

1.1 HLXU111 Dub-Rot 53.33306    -6.24889
2.1 HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.9225 4.47917
3.1 HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.225  4.7917
1.2 HLXU111 Dub-Rot 52.84235105 -6.16893985
2.2 HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.79675051 4.429912263
3.2 HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.925  4.4917
1.3 HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.55237595 -5.79583915
2.3 HLXU111 Rot-Kara    51.533278   3.430639
3.3 HLXU222 Rot-Kara    51.922  4.4791
1.4 HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.061667   -5.715889
2.4 HLXU111 Rot-Kara    49.727861   -1.940028
4.4 HLXU222 Rot-Kara    49.72786    -1.94002
1.5 HLXU111 Dub-Rot 50.08522105 -5.4050098
```

Comment: Power Query is your friend. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/keep-or-remove-duplicate-rows-power-query-d9cffc69-dc5d-4d94-8b66-72779688874d

Comment: Hi @ASH thank you for your reply. Here I don't wish to delete all the duplicates permanently, but I am looking for a solution which can dynamically update my map timestamp each time I filter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to overcome this issue by creating new column, which generates unique `No`

```
!no = RANKX(His_data, COMBINEVALUES(",", His_data[Container_No],COMBINEVALUES("-",[From],[To])),, ASC, DENSE) + ([no]/10)
```